# Чтение из файла(СИ)

Tags: c

При бинарном чтение из файла записывает мусор в 1 коэффициент,остальное все отлично. Текстовое чтение вообще не знаю,как организовать,вот код:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1865879.html#post9841925

Comment: Минимально воспроизводимый пример нужен в вопросе.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Никому в вашей простыне кода разбираться не интересно.

Comment: ошибка в 30-33 строках. В цикле в 30 строке начинается с n и до 0. А сам массив имеет размер в n элементов. Таким образом при первой записи в массив пишете за пределы. Аналогично и в 43 и других. Скорее всего нужно вместо `i=n` написать `i=n-1`.

Comment: @KoVadim: Надо сначала решить, что такое `n` - степень полинома или размер массива коэффициентов. Полином степени `n` имеет `n+1` коэффициент. Если `n` - именно степень полинома, то тогда наоброт, надо размер массива увеличить до `n+1` и везде об этом поминить.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего "отличного" там нет.

Если степень полинома равна `n`, то количество коэффициентов у такого полинома - `n+1`. Вы об этом прекрасно знаете, ибо в функции `Enter` вводите именно `n+1` коэффициентов.

Однако память вы везде выделяете только под `n` элементов массива и запись-чтение делаете только для `n` элементов. Поэтому и в `Enter` происходит вылет за пределы массива и один коэффициент потом теряется. По всей программе такие ошибки разбросаны, в том числе в функциях чтения и записи.

Вам надо сначала решить, что такое `n` - степень полинома или размер массива коэффициентов. Если `n` - именно степень полинома, то тогда размер массива увеличить до `n+1` и везде об этом поминить. Если `n` - именно размер массива коэффициентов, то тогда надо помнить, что степень полинома - `n-1`.

Либо так, либо эдак.